# What is the right number to replace and why?

Tags: calculation-puzzle

[image: substitute a number in the fourth triangle]

[image: give a numerical value to "C"]

Can anyone help me solve these puzzles?

Puzzle from: [www.treningmozga.com](http://www.treningmozga.com)

Answer (score 1):

Since the OP does not call for "no partial answers", here is answer to the top

> the ? in the triangle is 4

because

> If you multiply the 3 blue numbers around the triangle you get 10x the yellow number in the middle. 5x2x4= 40  so 4 and 3x5x6 = 90 so 9 etc. so 10x2x2 = 40 so answer is 4

Answer (score 1):

Further to [@DrD's finding](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/114334/60644) that the answer to the first puzzle is:

> 4 - since for each triangle you can multiply the blue numbers on each side and divide by 10 to obtain the central number (thus, 2*2*10/10 is 4)

The answer to the second is that C equals:

> 12 - since you just need to **sum the values of all symbols in cells adjacent to the letter-marked cell of interest**. (Here, 'adjacent' includes diagonally adjacent cells as well as those that are horizontally or vertically adjacent.)
>
>  A = 2 suns + 1 star + 1 lightning bolt = 2*4 + 3 + 2 = 13
>  B = 1 sun + 1 star + 1 lightning bolt = 4 + 3 + 2 = 9
>  **C = 1 sun + 2 stars + 1 lightning bolt = 4 + 2*3 + 2 = 12**